# Por quê o Oracle não possui autoincrement?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Partindo do pressuposto que é sabido que o Oracle possui o recursos da tabela *sequence*.

Gostaria de entender o porquê de apenas recentemente terem implementado o *autoincrement* no Oracle, já que era um recursos existente nos concorrentes (SQL Server, MySQL). O que motivava a escolha de não implementar um recursos de *autoincrement*? Ao certo isso deve ter sido debatido algumas vezes dentro da equipe, então deve ter um motivo lógico.

Sei que existem maneiras de manualmente implementar *autoincrement*, mas gostaria de entender o que os levou a abrir mão do recurso nativamente.

Comment: Já é possível no Oracle Database 12c Release 1.

Comment: poxa, se conseguir me passar a fonte, ou algum material para ler sobre?

Comment: Já tempos tenho essa dúvida e nunca soube exatamente o porquê. Graças que hoje podemos contar com o `idendity`.

Comment: Link oficial https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA109

Comment: @Ismael fica a duvida qual era vantagem que eles abrira mão

Comment: Difícil saber o verdadeiro motivo, provavelmente não foi implementado porque o conceito de valor único para PKs e FKs é muito abstrato, eu posso fazer um VALOR_ANTIGO+1 como o AUTO_INCREMENT assim como eu posso gerar um UUID que atingir o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Para mim o oracle sempre buscou deixar tudo muito explicito que ta sendo feito, deixando vc realmente escolher o valor da chave e bucar o valor no current por exemplo. Na minha cabeça era um decisão nesta linha.

Comment: Bom, o fato é que a Oracle não deixou essa necessidade sem cuidados, é possível atingir o mesmo resultado com uma trigger e uma sequence bastante simples.

Comment: Creio que só o senhor. Lawrence Joseph Ellison poderia responder isto, este tipo de chave em geral é uma ultima solução de modelagem quando não se acha uma chave natural , pode vir daí a antiga "implicância" da Oracle em relação à isto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir da versão 12c já é possível utilizar esse recurso.
De uma olhada nesse [link](http://www.rodrigomourao.com.br/oracle-12c-campos-auto-incremento/).

Agora, a razão exata pela não implementação antes, só seria possível de obter através de alguma nota da própria Oracle, porém uma "justificativa" interessante abordada por [Gary Myers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25714/gary-myers) em uma [pergunta semelhante](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204372/why-oracle-does-not-have-autoincrement-feature-for-primary-keys) é:

> Pode ser apenas terminologia. "AUTOINCREMENT" implica que um registro
>   103 vai ser criado entre os registros 102 e 104. Em um ambiente de
>   clusters, isso não é necessariamente o caso das sequences. Um nó pode
>   inserir 100, 101, 102 enquanto outro nó está inserindo 110, 111, 112, 
>   de modo que os registros estão "fora de ordem". (É claro que o termo
>   sequence tem a mesma implicação.)
>
> Se você escolher não seguir o modelo de sequence, então você introduz
>   problemas de bloqueio e serialização. Você força uma inserção aguardar
>   o commit/rollback de outra inserção antes de determinar qual é o
>   próximo valor, ou você aceita isso, se a transação falhar, você terá
>   um espaço entre as chaves.
>
> Depois, há a questão sobre o que você faz se alguém quiser inserir uma
>   linha na tabela com um valor específico para esse campo (ou seja, é
>   permitido ou funciona como um DEFAULT) ou se alguém tentar
>   atualizá-lo. Se alguém inserir 101, o autoincrement "pula" para 102 ou
>   você arrisca a tentativa de valores duplicados.
>
> Pode ter implicações para os seus utilitários IMP e escritas de
>   caminho direto e compatibilidade retroativa.
>
> Não estou dizendo que não poderia ser feito. Mas eu suspeito que no
>   fim alguem olhou pra isso e decidiu que eles poderiam gastar tempo
>   desenvolvendo algo melhor em outro lugar.

Em resumo, uma sequence pode fazer o que um autoincrement faz e algo a mais, além de dar mais liberdade ao administrador do banco para manipular esses valores.